# Classes and subclass printing

Tags: java, printing, subclass

I am trying to print the grade for the student subclass, i feel like i need some type of if statement or array.I am trying to make a code that can be passed a number such as 3 for "Junior" but can also be called through a code such Student.JUNIOR to print the grade level junior. my desired output is:

[image]

```
class Person {
    String name;
    String campus;
    String phone;
    String email;
    int FRESHMAN = 1;
    int SOPHMORE = 2;
    int JUNIOR = 3;
    int SENIOR = 4;

    public Person(String n, String cam, String cell, String mail) {
        name = n;
        campus = cam;
        phone = cell;
        email = mail;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Name:" + name + "; Campus:" + campus + "; Phone:" + phone + "; Email:" + email + " ";
    }
}

class Student extends Person {
    int grade;

    public Student(String n, String cam, String cell, String mail, int grade) {
        super(n, cam, cell, mail);

    }

    public String toString() {

        return super.toString() + "\nClass:";
    }
}

class Employee extends Person {
    private String title;

    public Employee(String n, String cam, String cell, String mail, String position) {
        super(n, cam, cell, mail);
        title = position;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return super.toString() + "\nTitle:" + title;
    }
}

public class Exam3c {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String name = "David";
        String campus = "Terry";
        String phone = "302-573-3254";
        String email = "Genos@edu";

        Person P1 = new Person(name, campus, phone, email);
        System.out.println("P1: \n" + P1);

        Student S1 = new Student(name, campus, phone, email, 1);
        System.out.println("S1: \n" + S1);

        Student S2 = new Student("Bill While", "Nowhere", "012-345-6789", "bw@nowhere.edu", 3);
        System.out.println("S2: \n" + S2);

        Employee E1 = new Employee(name, campus, phone, email, "Faculty");
        System.out.println("E1: \n" + E1);
    }
}
```

Comment: It all depends what you have learned so far. If you learned about enums, they're a good choice for this (though I suppose then you'd pass the enum itself rather than an int). If not, a `switch` statement or an array would be the tools of choice. BTW - there is no reason why the constants should be in `Person` rather than `Student`. Furthermore, they should be `static final`, not instance fields.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please visit the [help] and also read [ask].  Your question is just a dump of a homework assignment and some code without any real question other than "I'm not sure what to do next". This is considered off-topic.

Comment: meh..I think ill just stick to array and switch statements then..

Answer (score -1):

I think you're looking for enums. They have a lot of very useful features; in addition to being nicely type safe in a way that "Magic Ints" are not, you can also fairly fluidly treat them as Strings for debugging.